# Which Is correct: 2500 calories Is/are enough for the average man?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct: '2500 calories is enough for your diet' or '2500 calories are enough for your diet'?

Comment: Since _calories_ is being quantified here (there are 2500 of them), you'd probably want the plural verb: _2500 calories __are__ enough for the average man._

Comment: The correct phrase would be '2500 kilocalories is enough for your diet' :)

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: This answer is wrong**

Well, [this answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/303918/352751) indicates that both are correct.

> More links related:
>
> [Use of “Here's” before a plural noun / noun phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359055/use-of-heres-before-a-plural-noun-noun-phrase)
>
> [Calories Are/Is?](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CaloriesAreIs/gzccc/post.htm)

I also saw an article titled [Is 1,200 Calories Enough for Active Young Women?](https://www.livestrong.com/article/541609-is-1-200-calories-enough-for-active-young-women/), so it seems to be correct.

Comment: (1) The first answer you linked to concerns cases where a linking verb joins a singular subject with a plural predicate noun (not the case here). (2) The 2nd linked answer (using _Here's_ before a plural noun) doesn't really fit because the OP is not asking about _Here's some calories_. (3) The 2nd link (to englishforums.com) doesn't seem to have a definitive answer, but uses the plural conjugation when _calories_ is the subject (as is the case in OP's question).